# How to add a new row or delete one in DataBase from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, data-binding, datagrid

So I have this school project in `WPF` that I have to bind a `DataGrid` to a `SQLite` `DataBase`. In `XAML` I have 3 more `buttons`: `Load`(that loads the table), `Update` and `Cancel`(that cancel all the changes and reloads the `DataGrid` directly from `ObservableCollection`.
I have the `XAML` line here:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGreen" Height="245" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Userss.UserCol, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

I have a `Userss` `Class` where I created my `ObservableCollection` that store the data from my `SQLite` `database`.

```
public class Userss : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static SQLiteConnection m_dd = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");

    private static ObservableCollection<Userss> userCol = new ObservableCollection<Userss>();

    public ObservableCollection<Userss> UserCol
    {
        get { return userCol; }
        set
        {
            userCol = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Sex _sex;
    public Sex Sex
    {
        get { return _sex; }
        set
        {
            _sex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Stations _station;
    public Stations Station
    {
        get { return _station; }
        set
        {
            _station = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Jobs _job;
    public Jobs Job
    {
        get { return _job; }
        set
        {
            _job = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Userss> GetValues()
    {
        m_dd.Open();
        string sql = "select id,name,sex,station,job,date from user";
        userCol.Clear();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dd);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string sex1 = reader["sex"].ToString();
            string station1 = reader["station"].ToString();
            string job1 = reader["job"].ToString();
            string data1 = reader["date"].ToString();
            userCol.Add(new Userss()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                Sex = (Sex)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sex), sex1),
                Station = (Stations)Enum.Parse(typeof(Stations), station1),
                Job = (Jobs)Enum.Parse(typeof(Jobs), job1),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(data1)
            });
        }
        m_dd.Close();
        return userCol;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}

public enum Sex
{
    Male,
    Female
}
public enum Jobs
{
    Programmer,
    Designer,
    Manager,
    CTO,
    CEO,
}
public enum Stations
{
    Desktop,
    Laptop,
    Tablet
}}
```

And here is my implementation for my `MainWindow`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SQLiteConnection m_db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
    ObservableCollection<Userss> usersCollection = Userss.GetValues();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Userss.GetValues();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to make those changes?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                m_db.Open();
                foreach (var user in usersCollection)
                {
                    string sql = "UPDATE user SET Name = @name, Sex = @sex, Station = @station, Job = @job, Date = @date WHERE Id = @id";
                    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_db);
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@name", user.Name));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@sex", user.Sex.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@station", user.Station.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@job", user.Job.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@date", user.Date.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id", user.Id.ToString()));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                m_db.Close();
                usersCollection = Userss.GetValues();
                dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
            this.dataGrid.CancelEdit();
    }

    private void CancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel those changes?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Userss.GetValues();
        }
        else
            this.dataGrid.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

The problem i have is that when I press the `Update` `Button` the values that I've changed are updated in the `database`, but if I try to delete or add a row the update won't happen in the `database`.
NOTE: I've tried using `DataSets` and `Adapters` and didn't work (I belive because I put `ComboBoxes` in my `DataGrid`.
Any ideas what can I change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement specific events in your DataGrid.
For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Userss.UserCol, Mode=TwoWay, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
          RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding">
```

So in your code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // Only act on Commit
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        //execute your update SQL
    }
}
```

For delete is quite similar:

Add this to xlmns:

```
xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input;assembly=PresentationCore"
```

So in your datagrid:

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Userss.UserCol, Mode=TwoWay, 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding"
        ic:CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="DataGrid_OnPreviewExecuted">
```

And in code-behind:

```
private void DataGrid_OnPreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == DataGrid.DeleteCommand)
    {
        // Show MessageBox and get result
        if (result == No)
        {
            // Cancel Delete command by setting Handled = true
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // execute you delete SQL       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried before with the `RowEditEnding` and it didn't worked. It doesn't works now as well. The data that i changed after I press enter return to their initial values from `database`...

Answer (score 0):

You provide only update command for update data in database but not provide insert and delete commands. Try to use SQLiteDataAdapter same way:

```
        adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();

        selcmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        selcmd.CommandText = "...";
        adapter.SelectCommand = selcmd;

        upcmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        upcmd.CommandText = "...";
        adapter.UpdateCommand = upcmd;

        delcmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        delcmd.CommandText = "...";
        adapter.DeleteCommand = delcmd;

        inscmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        inscmd.CommandText = "...";
        adapter.InsertCommand = inscmd;
```

Comment: Also you must use connection, transaction, datatable :)

Comment: Using of events of DataGrid is bad way to bad school mark

Comment: Also you can decide this task without class for store the data from database using datagrid as data store

Comment: Ok, but how can i take the Id from the `DataGrid`? I see you put there a `selcmd` I belive that is how i can use it, but can you tell me how?